# Unable to switch to Alert without closing window popup in webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Scenario:

1. Enter a keyword (Position) in a textbox
2. press Tab or click on the next element
3. A window popup appears
4. a list of position matching the criteria will be listed
5. click the required record
6. Popup window closes automatically
7. Alert will be displayed
8. have click on ok button of alert.
9. switch to main window and check the position details

Question :- i found many solutions in the site but all are about performing actions on window popup and close the popup then switch to alert or main browser

but my application closes the popup window automatically after selection,hence i cannot use the driver.close() or driver.switchto.defaultContent().

If i dont close the driver (for popup) im not able to identify the next alert displayed after popup.

if i switch directly to mainwindhandle, the alert dismiss is happening instead of accept.

Please anyone who know how to switch from window popup to alert without popup close help is needed...

Thanks ....

Comment: Wow. You could help us greatly by building a reproducible test case, otherwise I will try to build one myself ... during the weekend. Also, just to be sure, could you show us your code so that we can make sure there is no stupid typo / forgotten mistake, please?

Comment: No Slanec im sure there is no manual errors boz the same code is working fine on IE & chrome but not on firefox(17 & webdriver 2.25)..The parent window has frames does that creating problems

Comment: Aha! That actually seems like a WebDriver bug. Retry it with the current Selenium 2.33.0 and if it still fails, [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list). That, unfortunately, is basically everything we can do.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/twist/2.3/help/how_do_i_handle_popup_in_selenium2.html) must be helpful for you . From your questions, Even after your pop up closes automatically you must be able to access your parent window element by switching back to it. There is no need of driver.close() all the time. Here is the code,

```
// do something with the pop up and it closes automatically here.
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("your parent window mainframe"));
// try to access your parent window element here
```

Comment: Thanks Karthikeyan for the link but the same code , if you observe    3) After the popup actions, switch the driver back to the parent window,
      browser.close(); // close the popup...i dont want this statement boz my application already closes the popup if i use this exception is displayed...i want to nullify this statement..any work around for this is appreciated..its urgent looking for the solution since 3 days...

Comment: Then use 'windowIterator = browser.getWindowHandles();' to get current active browsers.

Comment: Karthik, after popup window closes automatically there was only one windowhandle,when i use this to switch,alert closes but as dismiss..i want to act as accept to proceed.. some where im getting lost ...

Comment: @Shaan.aha Updated my answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

1. If alert dismiss is happening when you are trying to accept it, why don't you use ***alert.dismiss()***, it will probably accept the alert in your context.
2. When you switch to the popup window, the driver focus is on the popup window. What you might want to do is, just after clicking the required record, switch to the main window then accept the alert.

Comment: after clicking the required record,popup window automatically closes and alert displays.                                                                  Problem1: unless i use driver.close, webdriver unable recognize the alert ... i cannot use this boz application automatically closes                        Problem2: when i switch to parent window with handle, alter closes as dismiss , so either ways im not reaching to my expected condition that is alert.accept...the same script is working fine on IE & Chrome..problem in firefox browser..please any one has workaround le t me know....